# Is there any way to get server list with roles from config/deploy/<environment>.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

e.g

I have a file config/deploy/production.rb

```
server 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', user: 'root', roles: %w{web app db}
server 'YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY', user: 'root', roles: %w{web app dbslave}
server 'ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ', user: 'root', roles: %w{web app dbslave}
...
```

I need an array or hash with servers and their roles.

Maybe there is a way to rewrite config file to get it?

Comment: Maybe store the array/hash elsewhere that's easily accessible from anywhere and then iterate over it in the deploy file?

Comment: Thank you. Probably, this is the only way

Answer (score 0):

Create a service object that you can reference throughout your app:

First, create a services folder in your app directory:  `/app/services` and then add a service object named after the file so Rails loads it automagically:

```
app/services/server_setter.rb
class ServerSetter
  
  def initialize
    if Rails.env.production?
      @server_1 = {address: 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', user: 'root', roles: [web app db]}
    elsif Rails.env.development?
      @server_1 = {address: 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', user: 'root', roles: [web app dbslave]}
    end
  end

  def get_info
    @server_1
  end

end
```

Then you can check or reference it anywhere in your app or console by calling `ServerSetter.new`.  For instance, in your Rails console you could then do:

```
server_info = ServerSetter.new.get_info
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try something like this